# Как сохранить результат scrypt.hash в БД?

Tags: python, хеширование

Требуется сохранять хэш пароля в БД. Хеширую при помощи scrypt на python, получается что-то вроде

```
b'scrypt\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x01\x0f\xfaf\x8d\x93\xc0H`z\b3\x9d(\x08\x8b4\x85\x91\x02\xe5\x9e\xbd\xbf\xce\xc9\xbb\xa0\x81s\xfe\x96\r\x96\xd1*\x84}C\x83i\x97\xf5\xca+\x16\xe9l7\x9bnE\x90Z\xcc\xa0\xd4\x88\x98\xfa\x91\xda\x15\x997 \xad\xb0\x9c+V\xef\xb0\xb4m\x1bI\xd4\xa1{)Z\xb3\x98`\x9d\x85i\x9de\xdc\ro\xc1E`\xe7!\xc4\x91\xdd\xb3\xa3r\xe8\x1d\x1b\xa4s\xae\xc0\x82[\xc8.'
 -при использовании encrypt
```

или

```
b'\xda$1\x95\xa5,0c\x11\xc7J\x15\xefC\xb0\xc3k\xa2\x90(\xcd\xcbfe\xdd\xea\x9aT\x8d\xcd\xa8\xf1\xfa\x8b\xd1\xfb\x81\xf9b\x06ik\xb0os\xc7.\xf8\xbay4\xb1\xe8\xd2\

xd7~UwB\xbe$\x06\x16v'
-при использовании hash
```

Невозможно преобразовать это в строку. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Код прост:

```
import scrypt
hash = scrypt.encrypt('dg', '123456')
или
hash = scrypt.hash('dg', '123456')
```

Comment: Так это просто поток байтов. Сохраняйте в BLOB (или VARCHAR COLLATION BINARY).

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю два варианта:

1. Воспользоваться алгоритмом [Base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) для преобразования двоичных данных в строку
2. Сохранить значение хеш-функции в БД непосредственно в виде "голой" двоичной информации

Подробнее об использовании Base64 в Python можно прочитать [здесь](https://riptutorial.com/ru/python/example/27070/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-base64).

Исходя из этого, переписать Ваш код можно так:

```python
import scrypt
import base64

hash = scrypt.encrypt('dg', '123456')
или
hash = scrypt.hash('dg', '123456')

b64_string = base64.b64encode(hash)    # Это строка и её можно сохранить в БД
```

Comment: len(hash) == 64, но len(base64.b64encode(hash)) == разным числам, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: @Nerd0_0 Если вы читали статью о Base64, которую я прикрепил, то знаете, что каждые 3 байта кодируются 4мя символами. Следовательно увеличение длины в 4/3. Изменить это никак нельзя, да и не нужно.